# Code Breaking When Turned Into Custom Function?

Tags: r, function

I am putting together a summary table from a larger data frame. I noticed that I was re-using the following code but with different %like% characters:

```
# This code creates a df of values where the row name matches the character
df <- (data[which(data$`col_name` %like% "Total"),])
df <- df[3:ncol(df)]
df[is.na(df)] <- 0

# This creates a row composed of the sum of each column
for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  df[10, i] <- sum(df[i])
}

# This inserts the resulting values into a separate summary table
summary[1, 2:ncol(summary)] <- df[nrow(df),]
```

To keep the code dry and avoid repetition, I thought it would be best to translate this into a custom function that I could then call with different strings:

```
create_row <- function(x) {
  df <- (data[which(data$`Crop year` %like% as.character(x)),])
  df <- df[3:ncol(df)]
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0

  for (i in seq_along(df)) {
    df[10, i] <- sum(df[i])
  }
}

# Then populate the summary table as before with the results
total <- create_row("Total")
summary[1, 2:ncol(summary)] <- total[nrow(total),]
```

However when attempting to run this, it simply returns an empty variable.

Through trial and error, I have found that the line of code causing this is:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

The code works absolutely fine when run line by line outside of this custom function.

Comment: There maybe a better way to do what you are trying to do here but for this function to run, you may need to add `return(df)` at the last line of the function.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! Would still be interested to hear any suggestions to achieve same results in a more efficient way.

Comment: I think `colSums(grep(x, data[["Crop year"]]), 3:ncol(df)], na.rm = TRUE)` more or less  accomplishes the same thing

Comment: Alan I can see an unmatched bracket in there, do you need to make an edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments if you add `return(df)` at the end of the function, the function will work. We need to do that because `for` loop unlike any other functions doesn't return an object after it's executed.

Moreover, as mentioned in the comments by @alan that you can use `colSums` to get sum of each column directly instead of `for` loop to loop over each column and take its `sum`.